# No output when I pass "unhappy" number (e.g. 21)

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while

Program stops working whenever I enter the "*unhappy*" number and does not print anything

Here is the output:

1. When I enter the happy number
   [image]
2. When I enter the unhappy number (then output screen even after 2 minutes of time)
   [image]

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//This is a program to check if a number is happy or not
int main()
{
    int n, r, sum, tmp; // n = number, r = remainder
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &n); // input number
    tmp = n;

    do {
        sum = 0;
        while (tmp > 0) {
            r = tmp % 10;
            sum += r*r;
            tmp = tmp / 10;
        }
        tmp = sum;
    } while (tmp > 1);

    if (sum == 1) {
        printf("%d is a happy number",n);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a happy number",n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is working correctly, your program is failing.

Comment: 1) Could you please add also code output as text instead of as image? 2) Forgive my ignorance, but could you give us the definition of 'happy number"?

Comment: With input `21`, the loop `while(tmp>1)` runs infinitely because the value of `tmp` is repeatedly changing within some few values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering an infinite loop, because your condition in do-while loop is wrong, try: `while(tmp != 1 && tmp != 4);`

PS, you should learn how to debug, whenever your program does not respond, the first thing you should consider is an infinite loop. Never blame the compiler :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have just started  learnig to code and joined this forum recently.